# How to reference minified code, but keep developing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, minify

Our index.html refers to about 25 javascript files.  For deployment, we need to minify all of those, so we have to update our index.html references to the minified versions.

When we go back to development, we have to use a similar index.html file, but make references to non-minified javascript files.  Is there a best practice way to accomplish this without having to keep two index.html files in sync, one for development and one for deployment?

Comment: This question is subjective so it's off-topic, but why couldn't you just keep the same js filenames? x.js on a development server would point to the non-minified file, while x.js on the production server would point to the minified copy, provided that's what you loaded on the production server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is Source Maps, its basically a way to reference a minified javascript file back to an un-built state.

That way you only need one index.html file referencing your minified javascript file, and the source maps will help you debug them as if they were un minified.

Here is a link that really helped me.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

You could also use tools like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to make minifying and building the source maps easier.